# JavaScript: problem with swiper-button-prev

Tags: javascript, html, arrows

I have a problem with arrows on the slider on the website that I've published a few days ago. A link to a website is https://blackfox.ai/. The problem is that the left arrow (swiper-button-prev) does the same thing as the right arrow (swiper-button-next). In other words, when I click on the left arrow, I want the previous slide to come from left to right, not from right to left. Is there anybody who had a similar problem and can help me?

HTML code for these arrows is:

```html
<div
  class="swiper-button-prev"
  style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;width: 85%;"
  tabindex="0"
  role="button"
  aria-label="Previous slide"></div>
<div
  class="swiper-button-next"
  style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 85%;"
  tabindex="0"
  role="button"
  aria-label="Next slide"></div>
```

JavaScript code for the slider itself is:

```js
// Testimonial Slider Three
var testimonialSlider = new Swiper('.testimonial-slider-three', {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  slidesPerGroup: 1,
  loop: true,
  /*autoplay: true,*/
  autoplay: {
    delay: 6000,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  speed: 1000,
  autoHeight: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination-t0',
    type: 'bullets',
    clickable: true
  },
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You only _think_ that you are clicking your `prev` button, but you actually aren't. Both those buttons go over (nearly) the full width (easy enough to find out, by simply inspecting the elements in browser dev tools) - the 85% you specified, and the next button is on top of the prev one, and therefor "catches" _all_ clicks.

Comment: Okay, do you have any kind of advice to have arrows in the same position as they are now and that the left arrow slides to the right (to the previous image) and the right arrow to left (to the next image)?

Comment: Remove the width, and specify a left/right value for the absolute positioning.